# Filtros condicionales usando linq

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2017

Trabajo con C#, Visual Studio 2019
Tengo la siguiente query

```
using (var context = new BusinessContext())
        {
            var result = from ov in context.OrdenVentas
                         join c in context.Clientes on ov.ClienteId equals c.ClienteId
                         where ov.Estado == EstadoOrdenVenta.Emitido &&
                             (filter.Codigo == null || ov.CodigoNumerico.Contains(filter.Codigo))
                             &&
                             (!filter.ClienteId.HasValue || ov.ClienteId.Equals(filter.ClienteId.Value))
                             &&
                             (filter.FechaEmision == null || ov.FechaEmision >= filter.FechaEmision)
                             &&
                             (filter.FechaCaducidad == null || ov.FechaCaducidad <= filter.FechaCaducidad)
                         select
                             new UniversalExtend()
                             {
                                 Id = ov.OrdenVentaId,
                                 NumeroComprobante = ov.NumeroComprobante,
                                 Descripcion = c.RazonSocial,
                                 FechaEmision = ov.FechaEmision,
                                 FechaCaducidad = ov.FechaCaducidad,
                                 EstadoId = ov.Estado,
                                 Total = ov.Total
                             };
            return result.ToList();
        }
```

En el filtro debo agregarle un parámetro de estado el cual es emitido.

```
using (var context = new BusinessContext())
        {
            var result = from ov in context.OrdenVentas
                         join c in context.Clientes on ov.ClienteId equals c.ClienteId
                         where
                             (filter.Codigo == null || ov.CodigoNumerico.Contains(filter.Codigo) && ov.Estado == EstadoOrdenVenta.Emitido)
                             &&
                             (!filter.ClienteId.HasValue || ov.ClienteId.Equals(filter.ClienteId.Value) && ov.Estado == EstadoOrdenVenta.Emitido)
                             &&
                             (filter.FechaEmision == null || ov.FechaEmision >= filter.FechaEmision && ov.Estado == EstadoOrdenVenta.Emitido)
                             &&
                             (filter.FechaCaducidad == null || ov.FechaCaducidad <= filter.FechaCaducidad && ov.Estado == EstadoOrdenVenta.Emitido)
                         select
                             new UniversalExtend()
                             {
                                 Id = ov.OrdenVentaId,
                                 NumeroComprobante = ov.NumeroComprobante,
                                 Descripcion = c.RazonSocial,
                                 FechaEmision = ov.FechaEmision,
                                 FechaCaducidad = ov.FechaCaducidad,
                                 EstadoId = ov.Estado,
                                 Total = ov.Total
                             };
            return result.ToList();
        }
```

Pero si no le mando nada me trae a todos los emitidos, si es que no le mando nada no me debe de mostrar nada.

¿Como debería hacerlo?

Saludos!

Comment: Has probado con [parámetros opcionales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41251331/linq-filter-query-with-multiple-optional-parameters)?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Es lo que tengo

Comment: ¿Qué es lo opuesto (o quizás sería mejor decir complementario) a `||`? Porque el comportamiento que describes es justo el opuesto del que usas para los parámetros opcionales.

Comment: Por cierto, creo que has confundido los dos bloques de código (el primero debería ser el "antiguo" y el segundo el "nuevo" que has probado añadiendo *Emitido*)

Comment: Lo que pasa es que indicarle que tu parámetro es `== null` y utilizar la condición `||` estas automáticamente trayendo todo. Si tu filtro de estado no viene vacío se aplica sobre la base total de los registros.

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera el estado siempre va a venir emitido para todos los filtros

Comment: Entonces a qué te refieres con **"cuando no le mando nada no debe traerme nada"**? No está claro lo que necesitas

Comment: Cuando no le mando los parámetros que están en las condicionales el estado es harcode esta quemado en el código @PauloUrbanoRivera

Answer (score 1):

Sinceramente no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, pero el titulo me da entender que es lo que necesitas.

Lo que deseas es que si una variable contiene un valor agregar el where a tu consulta SQL? si esto es así puedes guiarte del siguiente ejemplo.

```
    public async Task<List<Movements>> GetMovementsAsync(string idClient)
    {
        using (var db = new LITEFACTEntities())
        {
            var query =
                 (from mv in db.Movements
                  select mv);
            //Query es de tipo IQueryable, esto permite hacer mas consultas
            //generando asi nuevas consultas SQL

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idClient))
                query = query.Where(p => p.IdClient == idClient);
            //Si se cumple la condicion agrega un where a nuestra consulta SQL

            return
                await query.ToListAsync();
            //Esto ejecuta la sentencia sql almacenada en la variable query.
        }
    }
```

Lo que hace el código es que si me envían un idClient válido, devuelvo los movimientos de ese cliente, caso contrario se devuelve los movimientos de todos los clientes.

Comment: Adicionalmente a lo que busca en la pregunta, esta es una muy buena practica cuando se quiere hace múltiples filtros a una consulta

Answer (score 0):

Lo que veo es que el nuevo filtro debe ir al final y no en cada bloque de condición porque sino necesariamente todos debería resultar en true para que pueda darte registros:

```
using (var context = new BusinessContext())
        {
            var result = from ov in context.OrdenVentas
                         join c in context.Clientes on ov.ClienteId equals c.ClienteId
                         where
                             (filter.Codigo == null || ov.CodigoNumerico.Contains(filter.Codigo))
                             &&
                             (!filter.ClienteId.HasValue || ov.ClienteId.Equals(filter.ClienteId.Value))
                             &&
                             (filter.FechaEmision == null || ov.FechaEmision >= filter.FechaEmision)
                             &&
                             (filter.FechaCaducidad == null || ov.FechaCaducidad <= filter.FechaCaducidad)
                             &&
                             ov.Estado == EstadoOrdenVenta.Emitido
                         select
                             new UniversalExtend()
                             {
                                 Id = ov.OrdenVentaId,
                                 NumeroComprobante = ov.NumeroComprobante,
                                 Descripcion = c.RazonSocial,
                                 FechaEmision = ov.FechaEmision,
                                 FechaCaducidad = ov.FechaCaducidad,
                                 EstadoId = ov.Estado,
                                 Total = ov.Total
                             };
            return result.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: De esa manera también he probado y de esa manera siempre me traera todos los emitidos yo solo quiero que me muestre los emitidos cuando se cumpla un filtro.

Comment: Puedes  probarlo nuevamente, ya que al poner en *AND* el estado en la ultima condición los registros solo depende de las propiedades de tu variable filter, si las envías en null sus propiedades,  te traerá todos los registros con estado emitido sin restricciones adicionales